# requestAnimationFrame(callback) with for loop issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures, requestanimationframe

Recently I find a strange issue with JavaScript's requestAnimationFrame(callback) method. This is my code:

```js
var callback = undefined;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var flag = 0;
  callback = (function (index) {
    return function () {
      if (flag < 5) {
        flag++;
        console.log('K  i=' + index + ' flag=' + flag);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(callback);
      }
    }
  })(i);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(callback);
}
```

In my expected, there should loop as following in console:

```
  K  i=0   flag=1
  K  i=0   flag=2
  K  i=0   flag=3
  K  i=0   flag=4
  K  i=0   flag=5
  K  i=1   flag=1
  K  i=1   flag=2
  K  i=1   flag=3
  K  i=1   flag=4
  K  i=1   flag=5
  K  i=2   flag=1
  K  i=2   flag=2
  K  i=2   flag=3
  K  i=2   flag=4
  K  i=2   flag=5
```

But in fact, the console log as these:

```
K  i=0   flag=1
K  i=1   flag=2
K  i=2   flag=3
K  i=2   flag=4
K  i=2   flag=5
```

What should I do to get my expected result using for loop and requestAnimationFrame()?

Comment: What's that thing with `index` and `i`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just doing a nested for loop to get your expected result?

Comment: @Bergi Emmm... Allright, as you can see, in this example, `index` and `i` is a parameter needed in callback function.

Comment: @RyougiShiki But why don't you just use `console.log('K  i=' + i + ' flag=' + flag);` and get rid of the function with the `index` parameter? Can you explain what this construct does?

Comment: @TW80000 When a animation is required, I want to use requestAnimationFrame to achieve it, and `i` and `flag` as parameters in my 
 code operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use ES6's let to make this job easier:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 for (let flag = 0; flag < 5; flag++) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => console.log('K  i=' + i + ' flag=' + flag))
  }
}
```

The above gives the desired results.

**ES5 Solution**

```js
function loop1 (i) {
function loop2 (flag) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
   return console.log('K  i=' + i + ' flag=' + flag);
  });
 };

 for (var flag = 0; flag < 5; flag++) {
  loop2(flag);
 }
};

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 loop1(i);
}
```

Comment: IE(even IE11) has poor support for ES6

Comment: IE11 supports block scoped declarations https://caniuse.com/#search=let

Comment: ES6 is really elegant way to code it. But always it's a pity that in lower version's IE it cannot properly work. Thanks for your ES solution, it can work well.

Answer (score 1):

The `window.requestAnimationFrame` is a asynchronous function, for i from 0 to 2, you initialize three outer `window.requestAnimationFrame` task；

After the first three outer `window.requestAnimationFrame` task, the i from 0 to 2, and the flag increment to 3；

At the moment, the i is 2, the flag is 3, you have a if condition `if (flag < 5)` in every inner `window.requestAnimationFrame` callback , so the inner callback only run twice（for flag = 4，flag = 5）and the i is always 2.

I modify the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
(function (index) {
    var flag = 0;
    var callback = function () {
        if (flag < 5) {
            flag++;
            console.log('K  i=' + index + ' flag=' + flag);
            window.requestAnimationFrame(callback);
        }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(callback);
})(i);
}
```

Comment: As you say, is there any appropriate way to solve it.

Comment: Does this code meet your needs?

Comment: The order of console log is not really the same, but the result is correct, so it can meet my needs.